# How to reorder particle 'number' along a path?

Tags: particles

It there any way to reorder particle 'number' along the active path ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to emit the particles from faces and switch from *Jittered* to *Grid*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The particle number is in order of emission - so to change the particle numbers means to change their emission timings and the look of particle animation.

Technically I believe its the index of each particle in the particle list. The list cannot be shuffled though (with python).

The particle index can be used in material Particle Info node, why don't you use the Location output instead to sort your particles? With some vector math you can also sort them along the path.